Vietnamese and Cantarell
I'm using Cantarell font to write an article in Vietnamese. However, if I use \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} then the font was automatically changed into normal LaTeX font. The same thing happened when I use \usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}.
If I don't use these package, then the text isn't generated correctly.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
%\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\title{Cantarell và Tiếng Việt}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction}
This is Vietnamese. Đây là tiếng Việt
\end{document}

Here is the result:

How can I fix that? Please help me.
Thanks

The Cantarell font has no support for the T5 encoding needed for Vietnamese.

So how can I fix that?

Use an unicode engine (lualatex):
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cantarell}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\title{Cantarell và Tiếng Việt}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction}
This is Vietnamese. Đây là tiếng Việt
\end{document}



If you're tied to pdflatex, you can use a different sans serif font that supports Vietnamese.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ysabeau}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{Ysabeau và Tiếng Việt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

This is Vietnamese. Đây là tiếng Việt

\end{document}



Thank you egreg, pdfLaTex is familiar to me, rather than the other methods. Is there any other san serif font that support Vietnamese rather than the above?

@anonimo I only see (clones of) Avant Garde and Helvetica.
